# Custom function for splitting string on Upper Case characters does not works as expected

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
public static string UpperCaseStringSplitter(string stringToSplit)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in stringToSplit)
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(c) && stringToSplit.IndexOf(c) > 0)
            stringBuilder.Append(" " + c);
        else
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

If I pass a string like this:

```
TestSrak
```

the output is the expected one : `"Test Srak"`.

But when there are two same letters where one is lower case and the other is Uppercase next to each other, the split does not happen:

For example If the input is:

```
TestTruck
```

The output is also `TestTruck` . Can You please tell me where is the problem and how can I fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this

```
stringToSplit.IndexOf(c) > 0)
```

In `"TestTruck"` the first letter(index == 0) is also a `T`, therefore it will not enter the `if`.

Instead i would use a `for-loop` and check if the current char is the first, then you can skip the split:

```
for(int i=0; i < stringToSplit.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && Char.IsUpper(stringToSplit[i]))
        stringBuilder.Append(" ").Append(stringToSplit[i]);
    else
        stringBuilder.Append(stringToSplit[i]);
}
```

Comment: This. Also changed `i<stringToSplit` to `i<stringToSplit.Length`.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static string UpperCaseStringSplitter(string stringToSplit)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i <stringToSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = stringToSplit[i];

        if (Char.IsUpper(c) && i > 0)
            stringBuilder.Append(" " + c);
        else
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code has been identified by Tim Schmelter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450527/961113), but if you are trying to append a space before the upper case character in the string, then you can try the following *(using LINQ)*

```
string str = "TestTrak";
string newString = string.Join("",
                         str.Select(r=> char.IsUpper(r) ?" " + r: r.ToString()));
newString = newString.Trim(); //to remove space from the start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToSplit)) return stringToSplit;
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < stringToSplit.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(stringToSplit[i]))
    { 
        stringBuilder.Append(" ");
    }
    stringBuilder.Append(stringToSplit[i]);
}
return stringBuilder.ToString().Trim();
```